# Unsupported 16-bit application

Tags: windows-7, boot

Recently on start up I am getting the following error:

```
Unsupported 16-bit Application
The program or feature "\??\C:\Users\Ourania\AppData\Local\Temp\ytl.exe"
cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows.Please
contact the software vendor to ask if a 64- bit Windows compatible versions is available.
```

I tried installing CCLeaner but it didnt find any problems. Also I tried running [system file checker tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) but again it did not detect any errors. The above file is always created on startup inside the Temp folder. Any suggestions on how to remove this error ? Thanks

Comment: I don't believe 64-bit versions of Windows support 16-bit programs like the 32-bit versions do. There are third party emulator programs, like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/), that may allow you to run them, though.

Comment: You will need to find out what creates it. Maybe looking at the properties of the file, uploading to virustotal or running "strings" on it will give you hints. Probably you got some malware and will need to reinstall.

Comment: Look in your installed programs list for "Logo Business Solutions".

Answer (score 1):

If your virus scan doesn't pick it up as a virus, it doesn't mean it isn't dangerous. If you're wondering what the program can do, try searching the program name (`ytl.exe`) on Google.

This page says it's not a harmful program and can be deleted through the software add/remove option in the Control Panel:
http://answers.informer.com/15662/what-is-ytl-exe-on-windows-7-task-list

This page also refers to it as safe, although it's only found on one computer. They also refer to the same distributor:
http://www.isthisfilesafe.com/sha1/76C83EC381DC65F64A22942CBFF33192A13AC3BA_details.aspx

I would say it's an outdated piece of software. If you can find the software in the Control Panel option under 'Logo Business Solutions company' and you do not use it, I'd suggest you remove it.

If you're unsure if you can remove it, try renaming the file under `C:\Users\Ourania\AppData\Local\Temp\` or moving it to another location. If your software and computer keep working fine, you can remove the program from your computer.

Comment: Downvote but no explanation, I wonder why.